# Ajax does not work in jquery for redirecting to php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Problem with ajax, when clicking the Properties button, it does not go to the desired page in any way. I tried to add a link jquery in the head and in the body.
I have two inputs and a button Save.
When the button Save is clicked, the input values are added to  tags, and create button Properties. Then when clicked Properties button, ajax should work, but it does not work.

search.php

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <input type="search" name='search1' list="doc" id="inp1">
      <datalist id='doc'>
         <option value="virgil">Virgil</option>
         <option value="alistair">Alistair</option>
      </datalist>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="search" name='search2' list="doc2" id="inp2">
      <datalist id='doc2'>
         <option value="sherman">Sherman</option>
         <option value="dejesus">Dejesus</option>
      </datalist>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button name='btn' id='btn'>Save</button>
   </div>
   <div id='div1'></div>
   <div id='div2'></div>
   <div id='div3'></div>
   <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
$(function() {
   $('#btn').click(function() {
      let inp1 = $('#inp1').val(); // the value of the first input
      let inp2 = $('#inp2').val(); // the value of the second input
      let div1 = $('#div1');
      let div2 = $('#div2');
      let div3 = $('#div3');
      div1.html(inp1)
      div2.html(inp2);
      if(inp1 && inp2) { // if there are both values create button
         let btn = $('<button>Properties</button>');
         div3.html(btn);
         btn.click(function() { 
            console.log('hello') // It work's
            $.ajax({ // when the button is clicked, it should redirect to another page, but it does not work
               url: 'new.php',
               method: 'post',
               data: inp1, inp2,
                  action: 'prop'
            })
         })
      }
   })
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Ajax to redirect pages.
Ajax is more like background threading.

In your situation, you should build a form with js and POST data to new.php via php.

Comment: Hi, this is a comment rather than answer. Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment

Comment: I couldn't comment because of low reputation so.